# Basis of the localization of a free module is the localization of its basis?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a free $R$-module with basis $B$. If $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, is $B_P$ a basis for the $R_P$-module $M_P$?

Comment: Do you know about tensor products?

Comment: @Quimey yes I do!

Comment: A localization can be seen as a tensor product and tensor products behave well wrt free modules...

Comment: @Quimey As in $M_P = M \otimes _ R R_P$?

Comment: yes! That was what I meant

Comment: @Quimey Thanks! that point of view is actually super helpful for me!

Comment: What is a basis of a non-free module? You mean a set of generators or a projective basis or what?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Woops! I wrote finitely generated when I meant free - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f : R \to S$ be an arbitrary homomorphism of rings and let $M$ be a free $R$-module. Then $M \otimes_R S$ is a free $S$-module, and any basis of $M$ is a basis of $M \otimes_R S$. This follows more or less by the universal property of the tensor product together with the universal property of free modules.

Comment: Do you not need $f$ to be injective here?  I understand your claim if $R$ is a subring of $S$, but maybe it is more general as you say.

Comment: @spietro: nope.